# wxpython: return value from Mainloop

Tags: python, wxpython

If I create a wx.app in a script and call the method MainLoop.
how return a value from wx.app to the script ?

```
 print myApp.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a way to directly access the wx.App object from within a wx.Frame, I don't know what it is, so it's possible I'm doing this the hard way:

```
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, app):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
        self.app = app
        #...

class CustomApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        self.value = None

    def SetValue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def GetValue(self):
        return self.value


app = CustomApp()
frm = MainWindow(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Main Window", app)
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()

print(app.GetValue())
```

With a reference to the app, you can call self.app.SetValue() from anywhere within the frame, and then call app.GetValue() after the main loop has finished to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, from within the frame you can reference the app using wx.GetApp() hence removing the need to pass it in via the **init** of your MainWindow